# How to merge 2 rows table in ActiveReports 7

Tags: activereports

I have a problem when design a file *rdlx in ActiveReports 7. I want to merge 2 rows into 1 row like in table html.Seem,table in ActiveReports does'nt support.Please help me!
Thank you

Comment: Please consider reformulating your question, do more testing and include code examples. The community has almost or zero clue of your issues. Tag the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To implement cell merging in ActiveReports, you may make use of the [Matrix](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/Matrix.html) dataregion than the Table control.

When using the Matrix Dataregion, the cells with same values are merged automatically. You may refer to the [documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/CellMergingInMatrix.html) for the complete implementation of the same.

Regards,
Mohita